# how to trigger AutoSys insert_job and sendevent stored in jil file in one shot?

Tags: autosys

I'm very new to AutoSys jobs and I have following commands stored in single jil file. let's call it, test.jil.

insert_job: job_A 
command: echo 'mock'
description : mock job A

sendevent -E JOB_ON_ICE -J job_A

I'm trying to run jil < test.jil. it doesn't recognize sendevent. How can i get it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jil file we can write commands like insert_job,
delete_job,update_job but sendevent is different command which should be triggered by autosys agent.
So you can separately create executable file in which you can write that sendevent command and execute it through CLI.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks this works. I moved all my sendevents to .sh file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a change in one of the last service packs. For your JIL you can specify status:

```
insert_job: test_job2
command:dir
machine:localhost
status:on_ice
```

The valid parms are:

```
FAILURE, INACTIVE, ON_HOLD, ON_ICE, ON_NOEXEC, SUCCESS, or TERMINATED.
```

Comment: hi this doesn't work, at least for the autosys version I have. I have version D11.

Comment: I'm not sure this works for D11 I know for the autosys edition it was introduced 11.3.6. SP6 version. I would reach to supprt and ask them.